# Using the Oracle HR schema, how to display the amount of employees in each country?

Tags: oracle11g

This is my query.

```
SELECT country_name, COUNT(*) as num_employees
FROM employees
JOIN departments ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
JOIN locations ON departments.location_id = locations.location_id
JOIN countries ON locations.country_id = countries.country_id
GROUP BY country_name;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
COUNTRY_NAME                             NUM_EMPLOYEES
---------------------------------------- -------------
United Kingdom                                      35
United States of America                            68
Germany                                              1
Canada                                               2
```

I tried to display the amount of employees in each country, but it didn't display every countries.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that not all countries (in your schema) have locations/departments/employees. In that case, you should use **outer join**, e.g.

```
  SELECT c.country_name, COUNT (*) AS num_employees
    FROM countries c
         LEFT JOIN locations l ON l.country_id = c.country_id
         LEFT JOIN departments d ON d.location_id = l.location_id
         LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.department_id = d.department_id
GROUP BY c.country_name;
```